# Cómo filtrar una petición GET mediante la url de Firebase

Tags: firebase

Estoy recién empezando con Firebase. Antes he estado practicando con json-server para crear una api falsa, la cual me permite mediante la url filtrar datos de un json.

Con json-server hacía algo como esto: `http://localhost:3001/test/?id=1&id=2&id=5` con lo que podía filtrar y traer los datos de mi archivo json con los id especificados en la url.

Mi pregunta es si se puede hacer algo igual de simple o similar con Firebase. Estoy usando la "Realtime Database"

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. En Firebase, los datos pueden obtenerse también vía URL, mediante una petición cURL o de otro modo. Pero, ¿el problema en concreto cuál es? ¿con qué lenguaje de programación estás trabajando? ¿qué código tienes escrito? ¿qué errores tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.

Como dice A. Cedano, lo que tengo que usar es una petición cURL donde le puedo especificar parámetros de filtro.

Muchas gracias.

En mi caso, no encontré nada que filtrara por múltiples id en especifico como con json-server pero hay opciones que se asemejan bastante.

Esta [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data?hl=es-419) me ayudó a solucionar mis dudas

Comment: puedes dejar una mejor explicación de como una petición curl soluciono el problema? a tu respuesta le faltan detalles; recuerda que buscamos que otros usuarios tambien se beneficien de las publicaciones. y estas deben incluir toda la informacion posible para que sean una respuesta de calidad... y de paso tu ganes reputacion..